# How to grep string and show previous word in a Linux file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

i have a file with a lot of IPs and each IP have an ID, like this:

```
"id":340,"ip":"10.38.6.25"
"id":341,"ip":"10.38.6.26"
"id":345,"ip":"10.38.6.27"
"id":346,"ip":"110.38.6.27"
```

Below this Ips and after these Ips the file have more information, its a output to an API call..

I need, `grep` a IP and then the command shows the id, just the number. Like this:

```
345
```

EDIT: More information, the ip will be different every time, i need to pass the IP by argument. I cant parse the IP to the syntax X/X/X/X...

any ideas?

Comment: The input looks like *broken* JSON. Where does it come from?

Comment: Comes froma API call.. I need to get ID from a desire IP. :)

Comment: Use `jq` for that

Comment: what is jq? I dont kow this concept...

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: @hek2mgl: Provided a bit of a hacky way to do this, but added a disclaimer for not recommending it.

Comment: @hectormarina, apparently, you have posted only a part of the original JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look up a single IP, use this:

```
jq ".collection|.[]|select(.ip==\"10.38.6.3\").id" data.json
```

If you must set IP in an argument, then write a one-liner bash script like this:

```
jq ".collection|.[]|select(.ip==\"$2\").id" "$1"
```

And call it like this:

```
./script data.json 10.38.6.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your current requirement is get the IDs from your broke `json` file, re-formatting my earlier answer.

Though I do **NOT** recommend this solution to get the `ID`, a hacky way to do this would be to use `grep` in PCRE mode. The way I have done the logic is to get the IP string and get the characters before it. I am not sure how to extract the digit from `id` alone which returns me

```
317,"ip":"10.38.6.2"
```

So using `process-substitution` to get the value before the first `,` as below.

```
IFS="," read -r id _< <(grep -Po ".{0,4}\"ip\":\"10.38.6.2\"" file); printf "%s\n" "$id"
317

IFS="," read -r id _< <(grep -Po ".{0,4}\"ip\":\"10.38.6.3\"" file); printf "%s\n" "$id"
318
```

Just add the IP you need as part of the `grep` string.

The below logic applies only to the your initial inputs.

Using multi-character de-limiters `;` and `,` in `awk`, we can do something like:-

```
awk -F'[:,]' '/10\.38\.6\.27/{print $2}' file
345
```

A better way would be to use the `match` syntax equivalent to the awk `//` regex feature to use the variables of your choice. Provide the input IP you want in the following format.

```
input='"10\\.38\\.6\\.25"'
awk -F'[:,]' -v var="$input" '{ if ( match( $0, var )) {print $2};}' file
340
```

A more robust way to avoid matching incorrect lines would be to use `"` also as delimiter and do a direct match with the IP as suggested by [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl).

```
awk -F'[:,"]' -v var="$input" '$9==var{print $4}' file
340
```

Comment: But we need to pass the ip by a argument in a script, i cant parse the ip that i received by argument to the sintax that you wrote... I dont know if i explain corretly.. I need some like this -> cat file.txt | grep 192.168.1.1 and the output be the number ID.

Comment: the regex in your `/.../` is not safe. think about an IP: `210.38.6.27` with your pattern : `/10\.38\.6\.27/`

Comment: @Inian, there are no downvotes on your answer. Click on the counter.

Comment: @Inian so far there is no any downvote on this answer..  someone just withdrew the upvote.

Comment: ... indeed. And this was me. I mean `appreciate it!` is not the right response to a flaw in your code. Fix it! Also there is another request from the OP which you didn't responded to at all.

Comment: @hectormarina: Refer my update feeding input from a `bash` variable to `awk`

Comment: You introduced new problems. The match is still not working properly. It would match things like `10t38t6t25`, or `110.38.6.255`

Comment: @hek2mgl; Still at loss how to fix it retaining the `match` syntax

Comment: This solution could be perfect by below the lines that i posted the file have more data.. I need to grep the IP and then do the awk in the same line i guess.

Comment: You do not need `grep` when using `awk`, just pass the IP you need as a `bash` variable and set it to `-v` in awk

Comment: @Inian You need to `ip='"10\\.38\\.6\\.25"'` to make the `match` work properly. I still recommend a fixed string comparison like I showed.

Comment: getting a weird line `awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'` for it, did that previously

Comment: @Inian Doesnt work men, i use your command and the output is the start of the file... Like i posted in my last comment, this text is in the middle of a big text file.. You know? if you need i cant post the file complete. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Inian Yeah, that's why I'm using two backslashes

Comment: @Inian Good. Now, after the update I think that this is a *broken* JSON problem Probably the OP can use `jq` here. I'm not sure if he broke the JSON while posting it here or if it is really broken. Probably the first.

Comment: @JamesBrown: OP changed his input file later. He wanted the solution on his  broken `json` file for which just use only the `grep` logic

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '/10\.38\.6\.25/ {gsub("\"","");split($1,a,":") ;print a[2]}' ip
340
```

or

```
awk -F, -v ipin="10.38.6.25" '$0 ~ ipin {gsub("\"","");split($1,a,":") ;print a[2]}' ip
```

Answer (score 0):

grep

```
grep -Po ':\K\d+(?=,"ip":"xx\.xx\.xx\.xx")' file
```

Comment: Not really portable and it would require that you escape the `.` in the IP if you want to pass it as an argument to it. I prefer awk using a fixed string comparison without a regex. Just my two cents

Answer (score 0):

Grep, SED, and AWK are inappropriate tools for JSON parsing. You whether need a tool specially designed for working with JSON data (e.g. `jq`), or write a script in a language that supports JSON parsing in one way, or another (examples: PHP, Perl, JavaScript).

**JQ**

One of the easiest ways is to use the `jq` tool (as mentioned in the comments to the question), e.g.:

```
jq '.collection[] | if .ip == "10.38.6.3" then .id else empty end' < file.json
```

**PHP**

Alternatively, you can write a simple tool in PHP, for example. PHP has a built-in JSON support.

*ip-ids.php*

```
<?php
$ip = trim($argv[1]);

$json = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json['collection'] as $e) {
  if ($e['ip'] == $ip)
    echo $e['id'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

*(sanity checks are skipped for the sake of simplicity)*

*Usage*

```
php ip-ids.php '10.38.6.3'
```

**Node.js**

If you have Node installed, the following script can be used as a universal solution. You can pass any IP as the first argument, and the script will output a list of corresponding IDs.

*ip-ids.js*

```
#!/usr/bin/node
var fs = require('fs');
var ip = process.argv[2];

var json = fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf-8');
json = JSON.parse(json);

for (var i = 0; i < json.collection.length; i++) {
  if (json.collection[i]['ip'] === ip)
    console.log(json.collection[i]['id']);
}
```

*Usage*

```
node ip-ids.js '10.38.6.3'
```

or, if the executable permissions are set (`chmod +x ip-ids.js`):

```
./ip-ids.js '10.38.6.3'
```

Note, I have skipped sanity checks in the script for the sake of simplicity.

**Conclusion**

Now you can see that it is pretty easy to use `jq`. Scripting solutions are slightly more verbose, but not too difficult as well. Both approaches are flexible. You don't have to rely on positions of sub-strings in the JSON string, or to resort to hacks that you will most likely forget after a couple of weeks. The script solutions are reliable and readable (and thus easily maintainable), as opposed to tricky AWK/GREP/SED expressions.

**Original answer**

This is the original answer for the case of a file in the following format (I didn't know that the input is in JSON format). Still, this solution seems to work even with the partial JSON you currently pasted into the question.

```
"id":340,"ip":"10.38.6.25"
"id":341,"ip":"10.38.6.26"
"id":345,"ip":"10.38.6.27"
```

Perl version:

```
perl -ne '/"id":(\d+).*"ip":"10\.38\.6\.27"/ and print "$1\n"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, -v grep="10.38.6.26" '$2 ~ "\"" grep "\"" && sub(/^.*:/,"",$1) {print $1}' foo
341
```

Answer (score 0):

You example is not valid JSON.  In order to get valid JSON you have to add curly braces.  This is done by the `sed` in the following example.

```
$ sed 's/^/{/;s/$/}/' <<EOF | jq -s 'map(select(.ip == "10.38.6.27")) | map(.id) | .[]'
> "id":340,"ip":"10.38.6.25"
> "id":341,"ip":"10.38.6.26"
> "id":345,"ip":"10.38.6.27"
> "id":346,"ip":"110.38.6.27"
> EOF
345
```

Normally `jq` reads just one object. With the option `-s` `jq` reads all objects, because you have a list input. The first `map` iterates over the list and selects only those objects with the matching attribute `ip`. This is the same as a `grep`. The second `map` takes just the `id` attribute from the result and the final `.[]` the the opposite to the `-s` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your json pretty and then do cat file, below command might help

```
cat /tmp/file|grep -B 1 "ipaddress"|grep -w id|tr  ' ' '\0'|cut -d: -f2|cut -d, -f1
```